# reorder is not sorting bars correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to sort facet bars by a numeric value via `reorder()`, but I can't seem to get it to work. I pasted my approach below.

[image]

```
    dat <- structure(list(item1 = c("word 2", "word 2", "word 2", "word 2", 
                                    "word 1", "word 1", "word 1", "word 2", "word 1", "word 1", "word 1", 
                                    "word 2", "word 2", "word 2", "word 1", "word 2", "word 1", "word 2", 
                                    "word 1", "word 1"), item2 = c("ir", "pr", "no", "mi", "wi", 
                                                                   "pr", "fe", "pa", "ti", "la", "pa", "ex",
                                                                   "cy", "se", "pe", "ti", 
                                                                   "qu", "qu", "se", "pr"), 
                          correlation = c(0.25456134079712, 0.2519936013674, 0.235943369717533, 
                                          0.227471817443391, 0.226966823585789, 0.211693332876911,
                                          0.209447353365894, 0.207110281022818, 0.19877845972944, 
                                          0.191606462402359, 0.186883665554187, 0.179251580064878, 
                                          0.17330384364747, 0.163131910906122, 0.163131910906122, 
                                          0.154238168542876, 0.153535076033027, 0.146798885015777, 
                                          0.144380422722292, 0.142845908676349)), 
                     class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                               "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))

    library(tidyverse)
    ggplot(dat, aes(x = reorder(item2, -correlation), y = correlation)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
      facet_wrap(~ item1, scales = "free") +
      theme_classic() +
      coord_flip() +
      theme(axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

**Update 1:**

I simplified the example `item2` variable but kept two repeat values "a" and "b" that have correlations with "word 1" and "word 2". I also incorporated the suggestion to add `max` to `reorder()`.

Each facet is sorted by its `correlation` with `item2`, but "b" in the "word 1" facet appears out of order. "b" appears in the "word 2" facet which seems to be driving the order.

[image]

```
dat <- structure(list(item1 = c("word 2", "word 2", "word 2", "word 2", 
                                "word 1", "word 1", "word 1", "word 2", "word 1", "word 1", "word 1", 
                                "word 2", "word 2", "word 2", "word 1", "word 2", "word 1", "word 2", 
                                "word 1", "word 1"), item2 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", 
                                                               "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l",
                                                               "m", "n", "o", "p", 
                                                               "q", "r", "s", "b"), 
                      correlation = c(0.25456134079712, 0.2519936013674, 0.235943369717533, 
                                      0.227471817443391, 0.226966823585789, 0.211693332876911,
                                      0.209447353365894, 0.207110281022818, 0.19877845972944, 
                                      0.191606462402359, 0.186883665554187, 0.179251580064878, 
                                      0.17330384364747, 0.163131910906122, 0.163131910906122, 
                                      0.154238168542876, 0.153535076033027, 0.146798885015777, 
                                      0.144380422722292, 0.142845908676349)), 
                 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                           "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))

library(tidyverse)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = reorder(item2, correlation, max), y = correlation)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ item1, scales = "free") +
  theme_classic() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

Comment: I think the problem with the ordering comes from some categories being present more than once. For example the combination "word1" and "pr" appears two times with different correlations, but is then merged into one bar. Is this what you want to happen? So the ordering should be based on the added correlation scores?

Comment: I think you want `reorder(item2, correlation, max)` or adjust the function as needed

Comment: Nate is correct. One of `reorder(item2, correlation, max)` or `reorder(item2, -correlation, min)` achieves what you were after.

Comment: Thanks @Nate and @Mojojesque. I added an update that gets close. I want "b" to appear in the correct order in the "word 1" facet based on its `correlation` value with "word 1". Is it possible for "b" to hold different positions across the two facets?

Comment: Is the best option to create two separate plots and combine with a package like `gridExtra`, or can this be done with faceting as I'm trying to do?

Comment: Why is "b" the only `item2` in both words?

Comment: @OTStats "b" is just a placeholder. My actual use case is like: https://www.tidytextmining.com/ngrams.html#pairwise-correlation. The only difference—and the reason why I am stuck, it seems—is that this example from `tidytext` does not have any y-axis words that exist in two facets like I do (i.e., "a" and "b" in my toy example)

Comment: @EricGreen got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm able to get you slightly there, hopefully this will help us figure it out...

I think the issue is that you need to create a few extra fields to help you sort. I found this post, [Ordering Categories Within ggplot2 Facets](https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/ordering-categories-within-ggplot2-facets), which seems to also be using `tidytext`. Looks like the author, Simon Jackson, arranges the data frame based on the relevant value (in this case it would be `correlation`).

In your case, I first duplicated `item1` to a new field called `word`, pivoted the data, then arranged the rows.
The only outstanding issue now it that your y-axis labels are `order`.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% 
  mutate(word = item1) %>% 
  spread(item1, item2) %>%
  arrange(desc(`word 2`),  correlation) %>% 
  mutate(order = row_number()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = order, correlation)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  theme_classic() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank()) + 
  facet_wrap(~ word, scales = "free")
```

[image: ordered facet plot]

**EDIT:**

Figured it out...
Ultimately, duplicating *both* `item1` and `item2` (to `word` and `letter` respectively), then saving the data frame was most conducive to getting the desired result.

```
dat2 <- dat %>% 
  mutate(word = item1, 
         letter = item2) %>% 
  spread(item1, item2) %>%
  arrange(desc(`word 2`),  correlation) %>% 
  mutate(order = row_number())

dat2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = order, correlation)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  theme_classic() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank()) + 
  facet_wrap(~ word, scales = "free") + 
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = dat2$order,
    labels = dat2$letter
  )
```

[image]

Comment: That's great! I just found it a moment ago and tweeted at the author.

Comment: @EricGreen Great! Just found it myself. Share your solution, too! It'd be great to see what the author suggested.

Comment: ha, i came up with basically the same thing. thanks for a great solution.